# how to do the commands in the right order

Tags: python, tkinter

i want to create_oval before nmap and it does nmap before he draw

```
import tkinter

screen = tkinter.Tk()
print("its me")

def return_target(event):
    global all_canvas
    all_canvas.create_oval(290, 54, 310, 73, fill='yellow')
    os.system("nmap -sV 8.8.8.8")


all_canvas = tkinter.Canvas(screen, width=2000, height=2000, relief=tkinter.FLAT)
all_canvas.create_text(70, 61, fill="white", text="target")
all_canvas.place(x=-1, y=-1)

tkinter.Label(screen, text="target")
target = tkinter.Entry(screen)
target.place(x=100, y=50)
target.bind("<Return>", return_target)

screen.mainloop()
```

i want to draw yellow circle before nmap start
ty for your help

Comment: Add `all_canvas.update()` before `os.system(...)`.

Comment: ty very mach :)

Comment: First you have to understand [Event-driven_programming](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). Read through [`[tkinter] event driven programming`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+%5Btkinter%5D+event+driven+programming+entry) and  [Tkinter understanding mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29158947/7414759). `os.system(...` is blocking.